# Space between elements in a column react boostrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I want there to be many small buttons that go across the entire screen. My setup is currently like this

```
<Row>
    <Col>
        <label className="btn btn-light btn-sm" style={{fontSize: "10px" }}>button text</label>
        <label className="btn btn-light btn-sm" style={{fontSize: "10px" }}>button text</label>
        <label className="btn btn-light btn-sm" style={{fontSize: "10px" }}>button text</label>
        <label className="btn btn-light btn-sm" style={{fontSize: "10px" }}>button text</label>
        ... and so on
    </Col>
</Row>
```

The effect is achieved, however, the buttons are all touching each other. Is there any way to force a padding around individual elements of a Column? I can't seem to figure out where to put it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many possibilities. You could use margin or padding or - what I would prefer - use flexbox with gap property:

- You could use given bootstrap classes and make Col a flexbox and use the gap property: `<Col className="d-flex gap-2">`
- There is also a component for this called Stack: `<Stack direction="horizontal" gap={2}>`
- Or, if you need custom gap size, use css in any way directly. For example with inline styles: `<Col className="d-flex" style={{ gap: "13px" }}>`

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-darkness-91d2ho

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. They all create a gap, however, once I add d-flex to the column or use a Stack, they all end up in the same row causing there to be a horizontal scroll bar. Prior, they would wrap around to the next row if there were too many to fit on the screen, which is what I am looking for. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, use "flex-wrap" class